# Path to a USB Device in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, device

I would be using a USB hub to connect multiple devices. I want to fix a specific USB device to a particular slot. Then check if it is done properly.

The way I am planning to achieve this is to get the complete USB path like

```
PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1D00)#USBROOT(0)#USB(1)#USB(2)#USB(3)#USB(3)
```

I can get this particular string in w7 via device property but the same is not available in wXP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build this path by using the SetupAPI.

The device manager is built with this.

You start with [CM_Locate_DevNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and enumerate children with [CM_Get_Child](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538074.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise you against what you're planning to do. AFAIK a USB device MUST function regardless on the USB port it's plugged in. If you'll creating such a device, forget e.g. about the "Certified for Windows" logo.

Just handle WM_DEVICECHANGE message, then use e.g. WMI to search for the USB device you're interested in. [Here's my article about it](http://const.me/articles/usb-detect/): that time I coded C# language, however WMI has C++ API as well.

Comment: What's bad for the manufacturer may be perfectly reasonable for the end user.  For example, I wouldn't want my laptop manufacturer to lock the wallpaper setting so it can never be changed.  If I as the computer owner wanted to do so, that's completely appropriate.